Ordinal enum mapping with Hibernate 6.5
I'm upgrading Hibernate from 6.1.7 to 6.5.2, there are many enum columns in my entities marked with
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL). My codebase has to run against both Oracle and SQL Server.
The problem is change in Hibernate to map enums from SMALLINT to TINYINT (if enums have only few values).
I already have DB schema fixed for Oracle as NUMBER(10, 0) and for SQL Server as INT for ordinal enums.
I can't seem to find solution to map enums with annotations that would work for both DBs at the same time.
Currently it works for Oracle, but schema validation for SQL Server throws:

Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [XXXX] in table [XXX];
found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [smallint (Types#SMALLINT)]

Any idea how to fix this?
I've tried to add @JdbcTypeCode(Types.SMALLINT), same errors.
Also @Column(columnDefinition = "int") which fixes SQL Server, but Oracle starts failing with schema validation:

Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [definitionRef_targetType] in table [m_acc_cert_campaign];
found [number (Types#NUMERIC)], but expecting [int (Types#TINYINT)]


Maybe this will help? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2944/comparing-sql-server-and-oracle-datatypes/ scroll down to Summary.

So, why not change the datatype in sql server to smallint? Or am i missing something?

It's a case of differences in database schema and definitions of your entities. -- It really does want you to align them both - either decrease the length of NUMBER(x, 0) in Oracle, or leave it as NUMBER(10, 0) but change column type something other than SMALLINT in SQLServer instead. Changing stuff in entity annotation will not help here.

Entity definitions worked like a charm with 6.1.x hibernate. And I'd like to avoid schema changes, too many deployments - both schemas for oracle as well as for sqlserver were generated by some previous versions of hibernate so I hoped behaviour of EnumJavaType handling can be "reverted" somehow.

Yes, downgrade back to 6.1

@siggemannen good one :D

Solution is to annotate it like this:
@JdbcType(IntegerJdbcType.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)

@JdbcType will force SqlTypes.SMALLINT as it was previously implemented directly in EnumJavaType.
